# Java Client-Server connection without port forwarding?

Tags: java, sockets, networking, connection, p2p

I would like to implement a connection between two devices with Java. Actually I am using ServerSockets and this implies that I have to use port forwarding because I want to connect the computers via public ip addresses. This works fine. But I would like to connect the devices without port forwarding or other changes on the router. Is this possible?

How should I connect the devices? Might be a P2P Connecion the solution? 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Maybe you should rely on a main server on a public ip with minimal port forwarding need (i.e. a dedicated server), which will route the data between your devices. The basic connection scheme would be:
Dev1 connects to the server, Dev2 connects too. Dev1 requests communication with Dev2, and then the server routes all Dev1's data to Dev2.

Answer (score 0):

> I would like to connect the devices without port forwarding or other changes on the router. Is this possible?

Yes, don't go through the router. ie. access it on the internal network. If you are using the router, you have to configure it.

> How should I connect the devices?

Without more details, I would suggest TCP is the simplest.

> Might be a P2P Connecion the solution?

It might.

Comment: Thank you for the quick answer. Do you have a link with more information? Is the access on the internal network also possible if the devices are in different wi-fi networks? I do not think so.

Comment: There is a whole internet of information, I am not sure what will specifically help.  Devices on different networks can talk to each other as long as the routers are connected and configured correctly.

Comment: I have a question. How can I create a global server? I have a VServer but I do not know how to install a java application. The User A should connect to the central server and the User B should receive information from the central server.

Comment: By global server, do you mean one that can bee accessed anywhere on the internet? If so you need to expose it via a public IP address.  There is nothing special to do to install a Java application, just copy it somewhere on the server and run it. User A & B need to be able to connect to the server, from a network point of view, there is no difference.

Comment: But how can I run the .java file? I did not find a good result, because I do not know what I can search for.

Comment: Normally, you develop your program in an IDE and you use a build system like maven.  The IDE helps you develop and debug your code and maven will build a deployment for you. It is the deployment you copy and run on your server. in short, to run a .java, open it in your IDE and press the `Run` button.